# Explanation of code using \titleformat

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am writing a project in latex and to make my output pdf look more fancy i am using a "Fancy chapter headings with TikZ" code found here http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/fancy-chapter-tikz/ (thx to author). But the thing is I don't want to just use it, I also want to understand it. I have never used titlesec package before so that's why i need your help. Can you give some short explanation to every line or at least answer some additional questions i have put in comments?Those are more imporatnt :) I will really appreciate your help and effort.

THANK YOU

Here's the code from that page:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

%EXPLANATION FROM HERE
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west) % why is here used current page.north west?
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1}; %why is here used argument by \chapterlabel?
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

%TO HERE

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
Text
\chapter{Main}
\section{Section}
Text
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Test} test reference
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you red the titlesec manual (e.g. via `texdoc titlesec` in your terminal / command line)? It should tell you more about the right usage. I think it’s not sense of this site to rephrase manuals ;-)

Comment: @KvJohn: You can find a nice explanation of `\newcommand*` if you search for `newcommand star` on this site.

Comment: @Jake - thx for the \newcommand* 
@ Tobi i am not asking for a complete explanation from manuals just short one for quick understanding cuz i really have no time to study manuals. But thank you anyway ;)

Comment: The LaTeX command `\newcommand*` acts like the TeX-primitive command `\def`, whereas the LaTeX command `\newcommand` (*without* the star) acts like `\long\def`. A "long" definition of a macro allows for paragraph breaks inside the macro's argument(s), whereas a non-long definition does not. This distinction is useful if you know that a macro's argument(s) should never contain paragraph breaks: by making the macro non-long, LaTeX/TeX will automatically trigger an error message if it does encounter a paragraph break, as this break is (likely) caused by omitted brace somewhere in the code.

Comment: Thank you very much. And can you pls tell me how is this last argument by \chapterlabel used?What preferences is this arg. calling?

Comment: We cannot really explain every part of an internal part of a package: it's far too mixed to make a good single question.